# ROS2 - New and need help subscribing to topics and creating publisher

Tags: c++, ros, ros2

I am new to ROS2 and have gone through some video tutorials so I understand concepts conceptually, topics, subscriber, publisher, etc. I am trying to solve a coding problem that is required for university using ROS2 Humble in C++.

I am supposed to subscribe to two topics: one of type std_msgs/Int8MultiArray and the other of type std_msgs/Int8, they always publish the same value at 1 hz.

And the node I create is supposed to publish the indices of the two elements in that array that add up to the int published by the second topic.

I have never worked with ROS before and would really appreciate some guidance. Also if you know any links to similar projects, etc. I would greatly appreciate it. Thanks a lot.

Comment: What have you tried so far? SO isn't a free code writing service but if you provide something you've tried that isn't working people will be more likely to help.

Comment: You probably need to ask your instructor. This is what you paid them for. Also, you need to understand the ROS learning process is steep.